# Unable to add App icon to my Flutter application using Flutter_launcher_icons package

Tags: flutter, dart, appicon

I'm using flutter_launcher_icons package for changing my Flutter app icon but I'm unable to do so. The following error is getting thrown

[image]

Comment: try removing space before flutter in your console. There is space before your command.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add "version" of flutter_luancher icon and can check it in https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons